# Microsoft Project, total resource usage by group

Tags: ms-project

I have Project 365 and I am trying to create a view where a task will display all the resources it uses, and then total them by group.

For example I have the Group "labour" where I've put all my employees, now that I've assigned them to a task I would like to see total man-hours or man-days for that task.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apply the task usage view to show all tasks andm indented underneath, the assignments.  You can create a custom group to group first by ID (Task Field), then by Name (Task field), and then by Resource Group (Assignment).

However, if all of your resources are in one group "Labour" then you really shouldn't need to group the Task Usage view at all.  The Work field will show you total work per task and the duration field will show how many days the task takes from beginning to end.